# The echo in php is not being displayed back in HTML page

Tags: php, html, mysql, cordova, ripple

my application gets the current coordinates and check if its there in mysql database.i m trying to get mysql data on html page (phonegap application). its working perfectly in mobile. but in ripple emulator it does not displays the data. PHP is sending the data back to html. i can see the data indirectly by going into developers mode(F12) -> sources -> ripple file.. BUt it doesnt display that data into html page.. What can be possible error
below is ripple file received code that i found in sources

```
jXHR.cb0({"headers":{"date":"Tue, 17 Jun 2014 07:07:51 GMT","server":"Apache","x-powered-by":"PHP/5.2.17","content-length":"181","connection":"close","content-type":"text/html"},"response":" *connected<br>1 somaiya<br>*
```

you can see the response: connected 1 somaiya is the data that i got back. But it is not being displayed on html

.below are the codes for html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
var lat;
var lon;
// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {

    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');

    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude  + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
lat= position.coords.latitude;
lon= position.coords.longitude;
var xmlhttp;

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("t01").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://geolocation.webatu.com/Radius.php?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon,true)
xmlhttp.send();
}

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
<div id="main">
<div id="t01"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Cross domain proxy to Remote in your ripple emulator settings

Comment: I did set it to remote but it didnt work !! Thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of XMLHttpRequest(), u can try with JSON jQuery may be easier.it having some inbuilt function.

```
Var Passvalues = 'lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon',
 jQuery.ajax({


url : geolocation.webatu.com/Radius.php',    
data: Passvalues,
dataType: 'JSON',
type: 'POST',
success: response_function
});

response_function(response){
 if(response.status == 1){
 //success response
 alert(response.message);

  document.getElementById("t01").innerHTML
  =response.message;
 }else{
  //failure response 
  alert(response.message);
  return false;
 }
 }
```

Comment: i Will check this and Reply to you asap .thank you for u time and help :)

Comment: Ripple not supporting Json jquery :(